# How to convert a String to UIColor in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, selector, uicolor

I am trying to convert an existing program which uses a list of predefined colors from Objective-C to Swift.
The original code used Selector to extract a `UIColor` based on it name represented as a `NSString`

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

-(UIColor *)getColor:(NSString*)colorName
{
    SEL selColor = NSSelectorFromString(colorName);
    NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invalid color name: %@ !!!", colorName];
    NSAssert([UIColor respondsToSelector:selColor] == YES, errorMessage);
    UIColor *mycolor = [UIColor performSelector:selColor];
    return mycolor;
}

+ (instancetype)turquoiseColor {
    return UIColorFromRGB(0x40E0D0);
}

+ (instancetype)mediumTurquoiseColor {
    return UIColorFromRGB(0x48D1CC);
}
```

However, I have been unable to work out how to achieve the same functionality using Swift 3.0, or whether the use of Selector is even the best technique.

```
func UIColorFromRGB(_ rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}

extension UIColor {
    public class var turquoise: UIColor { return UIColorFromRGB(0x40E0D0) }
}

extension UIColor {
    public class var mediumTurquoise: UIColor { return UIColorFromRGB(0x48D1CC) }
}

let myColor: UIColor = .turquoise

let name: String = "turquoise"
let colorName = "UIColor.\(name)"
let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString(colorName)

let colorSelected: UIColor = UIColor.perform(selector!)
```

> Error: ! No 'perform' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'UIColor'

Comment: Can OOper's answer be accepted for this question?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Color enum that has a default value of String:

```
 enum Color: String {
   case red
   case blue
   case green

    var create: UIColor {
       switch self {
          case .red:
            return UIColor.red
        case .blue:
            return UIColor.blue
        case .green:
            return UIColor.green
       }
    }
  }
```

Since it has a default value of String you can initialize the enum with a string:

```
  guard let color = Color(rawValue: "red") else { "handle invalid color error"; return } 

 let colorSelected = color.create //// colorSelected is now UIColor.red
```

Comment: That's a good answer, I've just converted my code to test it out. However, that fact that there is duplication of the color names makes it more cumbersome in my code than the other suggestions, since I have 230 named colors.

Comment: do you mean the duplication of color names with the naming of the enum cases? I'm not sure I totally understand what you mean by duplication of color names.

Comment: Yes, the fact that each color name needs to appear twice within the enum, once in the initial case statement and then again within the create. So it complicates things when I want to add new color names etc. and leads to more lines of code. So using those criteria, the dictionary suggestion is the most compact implementation. But thanks, it's made me considered all the options, and learn a few new tricks on the way.

Comment: I get what your saying now. 230 is quite a large number to do with the enum style. Glad you were able to learn something new. Enums can be very useful depending on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

You can write something similar to your Objective-C code in Swift like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    @objc(turquoiseColor)
    public class var turquoise: UIColor { return UIColorFromRGB(0x40E0D0) }
}

extension UIColor {
    @objc(mediumTurquoiseColor)
    public class var mediumTurquoise: UIColor { return UIColorFromRGB(0x48D1CC) }
}

let myColor: UIColor = .turquoise

func getColor(_ name: String) -> UIColor? {
    let selector = Selector("\(name)Color")
    if UIColor.self.responds(to: selector) {
        let color = UIColor.self.perform(selector).takeUnretainedValue()
        return (color as! UIColor)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

var name: String = "turquoise"
if let color = getColor(name) {
    print(color) //->UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.25098 0.878431 0.815686 1
} else {
    print("color with name:\(name) is unavailable")
}
```

But using `Selector` does not seem to be Swifty.

You can simply prepare a Dictionary containing `UIColor`s:

```
let myColors: [String: UIColor] = [
    "red": .red,
    "white": .white,
    //...
    "turquoise": UIColorFromRGB(0x40E0D0),
    "mediumTurquoise": UIColorFromRGB(0x48D1CC),
]
name = "mediumTurquoise"
if let color = myColors[name] {
    print(color)
} else {
    print("color with name:\(name) is unavailable")
}
```

Or JustinM's answer is a very good suggestion.

Comment: That's a very complete answer, it has unstuck me. I have tried out both options and both work.

Answer (score 3):

Use this extension of `UIColor` which have two methods for converting RGBA string and Hexadecimal String to `UIColor`

```
    extension UIColor {


    //Convert RGBA String to UIColor object
    //"rgbaString" must be separated by space "0.5 0.6 0.7 1.0" 50% of Red 60% of Green 70% of Blue Alpha 100%
    public convenience init?(rgbaString : String){
        self.init(ciColor: CIColor(string: rgbaString))
    }

    //Convert UIColor to RGBA String
    func toRGBAString()-> String {

        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 0
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return "\(r) \(g) \(b) \(a)"

    }
    //return UIColor from Hexadecimal Color string
    public convenience init?(hexString: String) {

            let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

            if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
                let start = hexString.index(hexString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
                let hexColor = hexString.substring(from: start)

                if hexColor.characters.count == 8 {
                    let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
                    var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                    if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                        r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                        g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                        b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                        a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255
                        self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }

            return nil
        }
    // Convert UIColor to Hexadecimal String
    func toHexString() -> String {
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 0
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return String(
            format: "%02X%02X%02X",
            Int(r * 0xff),
            Int(g * 0xff),
            Int(b * 0xff)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplification from OOPer's answer. My situation is that I do not have a collection of colour mappings. I have to get the colour from string directly. If it does not exist, use something else. Here is my extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor { 

    static func colorWith(name:String) -> UIColor? {
        let selector = Selector("\(name)Color")
        if UIColor.self.responds(to: selector) {
            let color = UIColor.self.perform(selector).takeUnretainedValue()
            return (color as? UIColor)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.color(name: "red") ?? .blue
```