# Save and retrieve UIColor from Firebase/Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, uicolor

I would like to save and retrieve a `UIColor` inside my project. I am using **Cloud-Firestore** and I tried it like this but it is not working:

**Save:**

```
batch.setData(["textColor": "UIColor.white"], forDocument: listRef)
```

**Retrieve:**

```
let textColor = documentData["textColor"] as! UIColor
```

But this gives me a `cast-error`:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1de9b9a98) to 'UIColor' (0x1de9ecd50)

What is the right way to do it ?

Comment: The way I solved it is to cast it like @JustinM suggests in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162951/how-to-convert-a-string-to-uicolor-in-swift-3-0).

Answer (score 0):

You can either save a dictionary which consists of the RGB of the color, or you can save the hex code. 
After parsing it, initialise your UIColor with it.

Comment: thanks for you answer, I laready solved the problem. Have a look at my comment